# How to create horizontal delimiter like in the Documentation?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, documentation, document-creation

Like this screenshoot

[image]

How to draw such line with *Mathematica* code?

Comment: `Graphics[{Gray, Thickness[0.002], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> .1]`.
Just for curiosity - why did you put `memory` tag here?

Comment: @Sumit It is not a simple line.It is seem some magic in it. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general when you have an element in a notebook that you want to reproduce you can right click on the bracket to the right of it, and choose "Copy as" and then "Cell expression".

[image: Copy cell expression]

The cell expression of the line in the documentation looks like this:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 InterpretationBox[Cell["\t", "ExampleDelimiter"],
  $Line = 0; Null]], "ExampleDelimiter",
 CellID->72220119]
```

Normally you can reproduce this element, whatever it is, by applying `CellPrint` to the cell expression. However, this particular cell expression to render in a normal notebook. I suppose this is because the documentation uses a custom stylesheet with styling that's not available to standard notebook.

To get something similar, you can go to the Insert menu, and choose "Horizontal line".

[image: Menu]

You can to type something in to the cell before the line appears. Now you can right click on the bracket to the right to find the resulting cell expression, which turns out to be:

```
 Cell[BoxData[""], "Input", CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, 
  CellChangeTimes -> {}]
```

`CellPrint` will print this as a line. You can change `BoxData[""]` to `BoxData["arbitrary content"]` to fill the cell with content. In this case it's an input cell but it could be a text cell or something else.

Making it gray etc. I'll leave to someone else.

Comment: If set the `CellStyle` to be `"Section"`,It will be gray. `CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[InterpretationBox[Cell[""], $Line = 0; Null]], 
  "Section", CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}]]`

Answer (score 5):

You can determine the "ExampleDelimiter" style by setting your notebook style sheet to the one used by function pages:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Wolfram/Reference.nb"]
```

and then using [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) to obtain the styles:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "ExampleDelimiter"}]
```

> {Editable -> False, ShowCellBracket -> Automatic, 
>    CellMargins -> {{48, 14}, {-5, 0}}, Evaluatable -> False, 
>    CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 58}, ShowCellLabel -> False, 
>    CellLabelAutoDelete -> True, 
>    TabFilling -> "[LongDash][NegativeThickSpace]", TabSpacings -> {76}, 
>    StyleMenuListing -> None, FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 9, 
>    FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSlant -> "Plain", 
>    FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.905882]}

The key styles are the [`ShowCellBracket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowCellBracket), [`TabFilling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TabFilling), [`TabSpacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TabSpacings) and [`FontColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontColor) options. So, to obtain an "ExampleDelimiter" style horizontal line, you can do:

```
CellPrint @ Cell[
    "\t", 
    ShowCellBracket -> Automatic,
    TabFilling->"\[LongDash]\[NegativeThickSpace]",
    TabSpacings->Scaled[1],
    FontColor->GrayLevel[.9]
]
```